# How to decrease the size of a logical volume/fs aix?

Tags: filesystems, aix, lvm

```
 oslevel -s
 6100-03-03-0943
```

IF I have a Logical Volume that I need to shrink, then how can I do it? [there could be several FileSystems on it...]. What is the process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use chfs like :

```
chfs -a size=*newsize* /filesystem
```

For example

```
chfs -a size=2G /tmp
```

That will set /tmp to 2Gb of space

For more info take a look at chfs' man page

Comment: and that is done online? jfs2? ty!

Comment: Yes, with JFS2 you can do that online

Comment: and what about the LV? :P :O TY!

Comment: also you can expand or shrinks LV online

Comment: the command chfs reduce also the lv size, check it with the command lslv -L after doing chfs resize