# Resize a btrfs partition inside a logical LVM volume

Tags: lvm, btrfs

Following derobert's trick to resize the underlying filesystem when resizing a LVM volume:

```
lvm> lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/VolGroup00/lvolhome
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
/sbin/fsck.btrfs: BTRFS file system.
  Size of logical volume VolGroup00/lvolhome changed from 3.04 GiB (777 extents) to 14.94 GiB (3824 extents).
  Logical volume lvolhome successfully resized
fsadm: Filesystem "btrfs" on device "/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lvolhome" is not supported by this tool
  fsadm failed: 1
```

The "problem" is that fsadm tool doesn't support btrfs resizing. Dispirited, I decided to do it the hard way (aka manually):

```
sudo btrfs filesystem resize max /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lvolhome
ERROR: can't access '/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lvolhome'
```

Well, btrfs can't "access" the device, but it can detect it:

```
> sudo btrfs filesystem show 
Label: none  uuid: 53330630-9670-4110-8f04-5a39bfa86478
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 2.75GiB
    devid    1 size 3.04GiB used 3.03GiB path /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lvolhome
```

So, what gives? How to resize my btrfs partition inside the logical volume?

Comment: does it work with the mountpoint instead of device name?

Comment: yes, it's supposed to be the path to the btrfs mount (not the path to a block device). Also, you may need to specify a devid (from `btrfs fi show`) if you have more than one device in the fs.

Comment: @frostschutz yes, it does. Curious.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, that was embarrassing. [BTRFS needs to be mounted](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/UseCases#How_do_I_resize_a_partition.3F_.28shrink.2Fgrow.29) to be able to resize the partition.

> How do I resize a partition? (shrink/grow)
>
> In order to demonstrate and test the back references, Btrfs devel team has added an online resizer, which can both grow and shrink the filesystem via the btrfs commands.
>
> First, **ensure that your filesystem is mounted.**

So, it doesn't matter that I was using a LVM volume, as long as it was mounted.

Answer (score 13):

BTRFS takes filesystem mount point as an argument, not a device path.

In other words, intead of this:

```
btrfs filesystem resize max /dev/vg/lvhome
```

You should use actual path where the said volume was mounted:

```
btrfs filesystem resize max /home
```